# SharePoint List - Daily email even when there are no changes?

Tags: sharepoint

(As far as I know) SharePoint list alerts only fire off due to a change. If I want an email to go out daily even if there were no changes, I figured I could create a calculated field that does today's date minus the "Start Date". It will increment by 1 every day. Will this cause a daily change email to go out? If not, does anyone have a trick for emailing out a list daily even when there are no changes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not cause the alert to go out. Calculated fields are only calculated when the list is accessed. The only way I see to do this is to create a site level workflow with a tool like Nintex or create a timer job that can generate the email you want.  Nintex Workflows can be scheduled to run on a regular basis.  Workflows created with SharePoint Designer cannot be scheduled out of the box.

Comment: Damn. Thanks! Seems like a very basic feature that would be handy.

Comment: I guess MS is going wiht a No News Is Good News approach.